# Method parameter type to pass a lambda expression prior to execute

Tags: c#, lambda

I am trying to retrofit some interface based abstraction to legacy code as a preliminary step for Dependency Injection. The legacy code contains lambda usage that I am struggling to encapsulate. Here is the existing lambda usage:

```
private void MethodAaa(EntityA a, EntityB a, int someInt) {...}

private void MethodBbb(DateTime date, EntityA e) {...}


_commandObjectFromThirdPartyLibrary.Execute(() => MethodAaa(a, b, c));

_commandObjectFromThirdPartyLibrary.Execute(() => MethodBbb(d, e));
```

I wish to route the lamda execution via a common base class method as follows:

```
base.CommonExecute( () => MethodAaa(a, b, c) );
base.CommonExecute( () => MethodBbb(d, e) );

base.CommonExecute( Action<???> lamdaExpression )
{
    _commandObjectFromThirdPartyLibrary.Execute( lamdaExpression );
}
```

Can someone provide an example of how to declare base.CommonExecute(?) properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using the [non-generic version of the Action delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx):

```
base.CommonExecute(Action lambdaExpression )
{
    _commandObjectFromThirdPartyLibrary.Execute( lambdaExpression );
}
```

Comment: I think I am getting close but to obtain a clean compile I had to use the following .Execute( () => lambdaExpression() ); The parameter signature of the 3rd party Execute() method is odd, it is some in-house UnitOfWork type. The legacy version of the code quoted in my question has been working.

Answer (score 0):

Non generic version of [Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx) is void-void one:

```
public delegate void Action();
```